# How do you draw this picture in tikz?

Tags: tikz-pgf, draw, pspicture

How do you draw these two images in LateX with tikz?
Note that D_R  and K_R are slightly shaded.

Thank you very much!!!

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX. You will probably get an answer by a TikZ user within the next 20 minutes. Maybe three different solutions within the next full hour. Let's see.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you do these things yourself, you will realize how much fun this is compared to having to ask.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[declare function={gauss(\x,\y,\z)=1/(\y*sqrt(2*pi))*exp(-((\x-\z)^2)/(2*\y^2));}]
 \fill[gray,opacity=0.2] (90:5) arc(90:-90:5);
 \draw (90:5.5) -- (-90:5.5);
 \draw[thick] (0,0) node[below left]{$O$} circle[radius=5] (90:5) -- (-90:5)
 (-0.5,-5.5) -- (-0.5,5.5);
 \draw (-5.5,0) -- (5.5,0);
 \draw[|-|] (-0.5,-6) -- (0,-6);
 \draw[latex-] (0,-6) -- ++ (0.5,0) node[midway,above]{$\delta$};
 \draw[latex-] (-0.5,-6) -- ++ (-0.5,0);
 \draw[very thick,dotted] plot[variable=\x,domain=-5.5:5.5]
 ({-1-gauss(\x,1,0)},\x);
 \draw[dashed] (0,0) -- (30:5) node[midway,above]{$R$};
 \path (-1,1) node{$A$} (2,-2) node{$D_R$};
 %
 \begin{scope}[xshift=12cm]
  \fill[gray,opacity=0.2] ({90+asin(0.1)}:5) arc({90+asin(0.1)}:{-90-asin(0.1)}:5);
  \draw (90:5.5) -- (-90:5.5);
  \draw[thick] (0,0) node[below left]{$O$} circle[radius=5] 
  (-0.5,-5.5) -- (-0.5,5.5);
  \draw (-5.5,0) -- (5.5,0) (0,-5.5) -- (0,5.5);
  \draw[|-|] (-0.5,-6) -- (0,-6);
  \draw[latex-] (0,-6) -- ++ (0.5,0) node[midway,above]{$\delta$};
  \draw[latex-] (-0.5,-6) -- ++ (-0.5,0);
  \draw[very thick,dotted] plot[variable=\x,domain=-5.5:5.5]
  ({-1-gauss(\x,1,0)},\x);
  \draw[dashed] (0,0) -- (30:5) node[midway,above]{$R$};
  \path (-1,1) node{$A$} (2,-2) node{$K_R$};
  \draw[-latex] (30:5) arc(30:45:5) node[right=2pt]{$C_R$};
 \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]